# Compiling OpenCV 3.0.0 in Ubuntu 14.04 - Error during opencv_test_video

Tags: c++, opencv, ubuntu-14.04, opencv3.0, gcc4.8

I run gcc 4.8.4 under Ubuntu Linux 14.04. I tried to compile OpenCV 3.0.0 downloaded from the [official download page](http://opencv.org/downloads.html).

After the following processing chain on the extracted files:

```
cd opencv-3.0.0
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -DWITH_QT=OFF -DWITH_OPENGL=ON -DWITH_VTK=OFF -DWITH_TBB=OFF -DWITH_GDAL=OFF -DWITH_XINE=OFF -DBUILD_EXAMPLES=OFF -DBUILT_TESTS=OFF -DBUILD_opencv_world=ON  ..
make -j4
```

I get the following error:

```
Linking CXX executable ../../bin/opencv_test_stitching 
[ 94%] Built target opencv_test_stitching
[ 94%] Building CXX object modules/world/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_video.dir /__/video/test/ocl/test_optflow_tvl1flow.cpp.o
[ 94%] Building CXX object modules/world/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_video.dir/__/video/test/test_accum.cpp.o
[ 94%] Building CXX object modules/world/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_video.dir/__/video/test/test_main.cpp.o
[ 94%] Building CXX object modules/world/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_video.dir/__/video/test/test_kalman.cpp.o
[ 94%] Building CXX object modules/world/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_video.dir/__/video/test/test_camshift.cpp.o
[ 95%] Building CXX object modules/world/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_video.dir/__/video/test/test_tvl1optflow.cpp.o
Linking CXX executable ../../bin/opencv_test_video
[ 95%] Built target opencv_test_video
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

With VERBOSE=0 on  make clean;

```
[ 95%] Building CXX object modules/world/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_imgproc.dir/__/imgproc/test/test_approxpoly.cpp.o
cd /home/hackenberg/opencv/opencv-3.0.0/build/modules/world && /home/hackenberg/bin/c++   -DHAVE_WEBP -DHIGHGUI_EXPORTS -DIMGCODECS_EXPORTS -DVIDEOIO_EXPORTS -D__OPENCV_BUILD=1 -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wno-narrowing -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -msse -msse2 -mno-avx -msse3 -mno-ssse3 -mno-sse4.1 -mno-sse4.2 -ffunction-sections -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -Wno-deprecated-declarations -Wno-deprecated-declarations -Wno-deprecated-declarations -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG -I/home/hackenberg/opencv/opencv-3.0.0/3rdparty/include/opencl/1.2 -I/home/hackenberg/opencv/opencv-3.0.0/3rdparty/libjasper -I/home/hackenberg/opencv/opencv-3.0.0/3rdparty/libwebp -I/home/hackenberg/opencv/opencv-3.0.0/3rdparty/ippicv/unpack/ippicv_lnx/include -I/home/hackenberg/opencv/opencv-3.0.0/build -isystem /usr/include/eigen3 -I/home/hackenberg/opencv/opencv-3.0.0/modules/ts/include -I/home/hackenberg/opencv/opencv-3.0.0/modules/imgproc/include -I/home/hackenberg/opencv/opencv-3.0.0/modules/imgcodecs/include -I/home/hackenberg/opencv/opencv-3.0.0/modules/videoio/include -I/home/hackenberg/opencv/opencv-3.0.0/modules/hal/include -I/home/hackenberg/opencv/opencv-3.0.0/modules/core/include -I/home/hackenberg/opencv/opencv-3.0.0/modules/highgui/include -I/home/hackenberg/opencv/opencv-3.0.0/modules/imgproc/test -isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -isystem /home/hackenberg/opencv/opencv-3.0.0/3rdparty/openexr/Half -isystem /home/hackenberg/opencv/opencv-3.0.0/3rdparty/openexr/Iex -isystem /home/hackenberg/opencv/opencv-3.0.0/3rdparty/openexr/IlmThread -isystem /home/hackenberg/opencv/opencv-3.0.0/3rdparty/openexr/Imath -isystem /home/hackenberg/opencv/opencv-3.0.0/3rdparty/openexr/IlmImf    -o CMakeFiles/opencv_test_imgproc.dir/__/imgproc/test/test_approxpoly.cpp.o -c /home/hackenberg/opencv/opencv-3.0.0/modules/imgproc/test/test_approxpoly.cpp
Linking CXX executable ../../bin/opencv_test_imgproc
cd /home/hackenberg/opencv/opencv-3.0.0/build/modules/world && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/opencv_test_imgproc.dir/link.txt --verbose=0
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/hackenberg/opencv/opencv-3.0.0/build'
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /home/hackenberg/opencv/opencv-3.0.0/build/CMakeFiles  35 36 37 38
[ 95%] Built target opencv_test_imgproc
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/hackenberg/opencv/opencv-3.0.0/build'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Seem to found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32996602/error-when-installing-opencv-on-ubuntu-14-04/33603464#33603464).

I installed

> sudo apt-get install libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-dev

Comment: try `make VERBOSE=0` to see the linking error. Btw, if you changed some stuff in the cmake after running make before.. try a `make clean;make`.

Comment: with VERBOSE=0 on clean

Comment: Nope, VERBOSE=0 on the make (`make VERBOSE=0` instead of `make -j4`). This will make it `echo` the commands being evoke. In addition, if an error happens, you see a better description. The `make clean;make -j4` is another approach to force recompile all the files again. This second approach is good if you changed any information on the cmake.. that need to apply to already compile files (and make can figure it out itself).

Comment: Check [this](http://rodrigoberriel.com/2014/10/installing-opencv-3-0-0-on-ubuntu-14-04/) tutorial by @berriel

Comment: Check also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33603464/5008845)

Comment: Can you post more lines when you tried with verbose=0? I want to see what library it is trying to link with and it is failing, or if it is another error.

Comment: Glad you make it work, voting to close as a duplicate then